# JS variable to HTML elements and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html

In the beginning I have JSON data, and I need to convert and output the list to html.

```
var frut = 
{
    "wtfrut": [
        ["0x01", "Apple"],
        ["0x02", "Orange"],
        ["0x03", "Pineapple"],
        ["0x04", "Banana"]
    ],
    [other irrelevant elements]
}
```

I made it an html `<select>` plus list of `<options>` . . .

```
<select>
  <option data-index="0x01">Apple</option>
  <option data-index="0x02">Orange</option>
  <option data-index="0x03">Pineapple</option>
  <option data-index="0x04">Banana</option>
</select>
```

. . . and stuck it in a js variable.

This `<select>` list is a cell in a table, and needs to appear in a couple hundred rows.

While building the table, when I need to display the dropdown, I need to go back thru and find the `selected` attribute of each `<select><option>`

### Problem 1)

The best I can get from

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
var options = document.createElement("option");
options.setAttribute("value", element[1]);
...
select.appendChild(options);
return select;
```

is `[object HTMLSelectElement]` where the dropdown was supposed to be. `return select.value` returns the `value` attribute of the first item on the list.

Therefore, I have resorted to stuffing `var dropDown` with raw html.

```
out += "<option value=\"" + element[1] + "\" data-hex = \"" + element[0] + "\" data-index = \"" + index + "\">";
```

because it works. `dropDown` winds up with the `<select>` and all `<option>`s. And it works when I call it with

```
"<td class=\"vkeyName\" data-f4key-index = \"+index+\">" + dropDown + "</td>"
```

### Problem 2)

Now that *that's* working, I try to take `dropDown` *back* to js at render time (during the loop that produces the above `<td>`) and figure out which `<option>` needs to be chosen as default for the dropdown. `select.length` returns the string length **which I understand. It's just a js string.**

### Overall

What I don't understand is how to get data over the threshold between js variable and valid html element, in either direction. To make that js string into a list of valid html elements that can be output to the html page... Or to take valid html elements, put them into a variable to be worked by js.

`getElementBy*` and `document.write` doesn't work. I presume because I don't have the document yet, I'm building objects.

At this point I'm uninterested in js libraries and helpers. This is a learning project and I want to understand this so that things like jQuery aren't so magical.

Comment: Use DOM methods instead of HTML serializing and deserializing

Answer (score 1):

I made a small example of a way how you could do create a combobox that generates an Array of some kind of data, and how you could help out yourself by using some callback functions to get the value and the text, and how to choose which element should be preselected, and how you could react on changes in the html element.

You can always use document.getElementById, but you have to wait until you are sure that the page got loaded, one way to do it, is to wait for the `window.onload` function to fire (which means that the DOM is ready to be manipulated, scripts and css are loaded)

In vanilla javascript, you can do it by registering a callback function on the load event, like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... });
```

To generate the combobox, I made a small helper namespace and added a comboBoxGenerator, that takes an object in, and generates the combobox in your desired targetElement.

I then iterate the data and for each element, get the value and text over a callback function (that you define when you called the generator) and it returns the value and the text for that single option. It also determines if the element should be preselected.

By registering to the `change` event of the combobox, you can then find out which element was actually selected, and for that I also added a small function that displays that the function got changed

The `'use strict`;' statement helps to add for example forEach function to the array, and will help you to keep your code more clean

I also documented the source a bit, so that you hopefully understand what everything is doing :)

```js
'use strict';

var helper = {};

(function(ns) {
  
  function comboBoxGenerator(options) {
    // get the element that you are targetting
    var el = document.getElementById(options.target),
        cmb = document.createElement('select'),
        option;
    
    // iterate the data, and for each element in the array, create an option and call the defined callback functions
    options.data.forEach(function(item) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = options.valueSelector(item);
      option.text = options.textSelector(item);
      option.selected = options.isSelected(item);
      // add the option to the combobox
      cmb.appendChild(option);
    });
    // listen to changes on the combobox and then call the selectionChanged event
    cmb.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      // this = cmb because of the bind statement on below
      // call the selectionChanged callback function, and assing the cmb as the this for the callback function (.apply(this, ...))
      options.selectionChanged.apply(this, [this.options[this.selectedIndex]]);
    }.bind(cmb));
    el.appendChild(cmb);
  }
  
  // set the combo function on the helper by either reusing an existing function, or the function just written above
  ns.combo = ns.combo || comboBoxGenerator;
  
}(helper));

// wait till all resources are loaded, and then generate the combobox
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var dummyData = {
    "wtfrut": [
        ["0x01", "Apple"],
        ["0x02", "Orange"],
        ["0x03", "Pineapple"],
        ["0x04", "Banana"]
    ]
  }, selectedValue = "0x03";
  
  // call the helper method with an object defining the data, targetelement, and callback functions
  helper.combo({
    target: 'myTable', 
    data: dummyData.wtfrut, 
    valueSelector: function(item) { 
      // item would be like ["0x01", "Apple"], return "0x01" for value
      return item[0]; 
    },
    textSelector: function(item) {
      return item[1];
    },
    isSelected: function(item) {
      // check if the item matches a selectedValue if so, return true, not false
      return item[0] === selectedValue;
    },
    selectionChanged: function(item) {
      // gets called when the selection is changed, item = Option, value is the current value, this = combobox
      selectedValue = item.value;
      console.log('selectedValue changed to ' + selectedValue + ' index = ' + this.selectedIndex);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="myTable">
  </div>
</div>
```